# How to find the solution to the differential equation $dy/dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

How do I find the solution to the differential equation:

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = e^{α(x+y)} + 3e^{αy}$?

where $\alpha$ is not zero.

Comment: Hint: how can you rewrite $e^{a+b}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The differential equation is separable.